# Small typo on common reasons for edits

Tags: bug, status-completed, spelling, help-center

On [HelpCenter](https://stackoverflow.com/helpcenter/editing) in section **When should I edit posts?** where the common reasons for edits are listed as bullet list the 3rd point should be

> To **add** additional information only found in comments, so all of
>   the information relevant to the post is contained in one place

The add is missing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I went with "include" instead of "add", but other than that... fixed!